# Track down Haskell segfault

Tags: haskell

This is **so infuriating!** >_<

I've written a huge, complicated Haskell library. I wrote a small test program, and so far I've spent about 8 hours trying to figure out why the hell it keeps crashing on me. Sometimes GHC complains about a "strange closure type". Sometimes I just get a segfault. *Clearly* the problem is memory corruption.

The library itself is 100% pure Haskell. However, the test program uses several unsafe GHC primitives relating to arrays. This is obviously what's causing the problem. Indeed, if I comment out the `writeArray#` line, the program stops crashing. But this is utterly frying my noodle... as best as I can tell, all the array bounds I've used are *perfectly valid*. The program prints them all out, and they're all positive and less than the array size.

I wrote a second program that does the same thing as the first one, but without involving the huge, complex library. I've tried and tried and tried, but I can't make it crash at all. Nothing I do seems to make it crash, and yet it does almost exactly the same thing with the actual arrays.

Does anybody have any further troubleshooting tips? Is there some way I can track down the exact moment when memory is getting corrupted? (Rather than just the moment when the system *notices* the corruption.)

---

**Update:**

What does the problem do?

Well, essentially, it creates an array representing a pixel buffer. It spawns one thread that iterates over every pixel and writes the corresponding value into it. And it spawns a second thread that reads the array, and writes the pixels to a network socket using a fairly complicated protocol. (Hence the large library I'm trying to test.)

If I don't spawn the writer thread, the crash goes away. If I comment out the `writeArray'` call in the writer thread, the crash goes away. Before writing each pixel, the writer thread prints out the pixel coordinates *and* the array index. Everything it prints out looks perfectly A-OK. And yet... it will not stop crashing.

I almost wonder if GHC's array primitives aren't thread-safe or something. (In case it makes any difference, the copy of the array that the reader thread looks like has been unsafe-frozen, while the writer thread continues to concurrently mutates it.)

However, I've written a program that does the exact same thing, but without sending traffic over the network. *This* program works perfectly in every detail. It's only the really complicated program that won't work. How annoying is that?!

This works: http://hpaste.org/70987

This does not: http://hpaste.org/70988

Comment: Even if you can't (or don't want to) share the library, perhaps you can share the test code?

Comment: @gspr The test program is kinda _large_. I doubt anybody is going to read through it all to figure out my problem for me. But I can certainly post it if anybody thinks it will help...

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build...?

Comment: I think it might help, if at all possible, to write a more detailed description of the program. The high level description you have now is ok, but some code snippets from the test program and some of the types involved would be great.

Comment: If you could put up the code somewhere (compilable, with hopefully no fancy dependencies), I could take a look. I enjoy bug-hunting :)

Comment: Wait, one array, two threads. In one thread you have it unsafe-frozen, in the other you still mutate it?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, that's right. It's not deterministic which version of a pixel gets read out and send over the wire, but that's not important to me.

Comment: Sounds dangerous. After an `usafeFreezeXYZ`, GHC assumes nobody mutates it (until the next `unsafeThawXYZ`). It might get moved around in memory or something.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, that was my thought. But the simplified program does the same, and does not crash.

Comment: Well, perhaps that doesn't need to move the 'frozen' array around? Undefined behaviour need not always crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Might be fixed:**

I changed something, and the code doesn't crash any more. That might be just a fluke, or I might have "really" fixed the problem. It's hard to say.

**Hypothesis:**

The problem appears to be reading from mutable and immutable copies of the same array from concurrent threads. (Even though the simplified test does exactly this and doesn't crash.)

I made the network thread read from an unrelated immutable array, and the crashing stopped. I even added a loop to copy the data from one mutable array to another, fresh, mutable array, and the fresh one then gets frozen and inspected. This appears to work perfectly.

So it appears it's just a glitch in GHC's handling of concurrent accesses to both versions of the same array.

(Either that, or it's a fluke. A few times I've changed something in the program and it's stopped crashing, and then started crashing again...)

**Update:** This appears to be completely fixed. I haven't had any more crashes since I made this alteration. Thanks to all the people who helped me out here. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You're already logging your use of unsafe primitives.

Have you written a program to look through these logs for violations of invariants?

Answer (score 6):

Replace your known-to-be-unsafe functions with their safe, checked versions. Inspect your logs for the exceptions that will result, and fix your code.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the difference between the test program and the program with the library is that in the latter case there is more allocation, so GC is called more frequently.

> The copy of the array that the reader thread looks like has been
>   unsafe-frozen, while the writer thread continues to concurrently
>   mutates it.

Probably GC cannot track that the mutable array is still referenced after freezing. In this case GC might move the frozen array, but writeArray# performs a write using the old pointer.

Comment: I have a sinking feeling you may be right about the allocation thing.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I know of that can be helpful is using Debug.Trace

```
import Debug.Trace
```

with

```
debug = flip trace
```

and then

```
main = (1 + 2) `debug` "adding or whatever and whatnot (also can have code here)"
```

Comment: Yeah, my code is already littered with `putStrLn` statements. (Since I'm playing with mutable arrays, it all runs in `IO` anyway.) As far as I can tell from the print statements, everything is working perfectly fine. And yet... segfaults.

Comment: Have you tried stopping GHC at the C (with -C) stage and painfully looking through the output? The CLANG analyser may be able to help you find any potential memory management issues then.

Comment: The version I have installed certainly has it. Oh dear, 'The "evil mangler" has been removed, and registerised compilation via C is no longer supported.' I must have a pretty old version.

Answer (score 0):

GHC treats mutable and immutable arrays of pointers differently for GC purposes.  Writes to a mutable array require placing the object on the *mutable list* and setting a bit in the *card table*.  Immutable arrays have neither of these.  So when you try to write to a mutable array that has already been frozen, you can write a new generation pointer to the old generation.  The old generation is not scanned during minor GCs, so when a minor GC runs the value gets collected.  Then you segfault because the array points to garbage.

Solution: don't freeze the array.  If you must, use `unsafePerformIO` for the reads.